# Is this a correct way to store dates?

Tags: date

I found this example of storing dates in the book Algorithms 4th edition, using only a single integer. I'm not sure if it is correct.

This is the class definition for a Date.

```
public class Date
{
   private final int value;
   public Date(int m, int d, int y)
   { value = y*512 + m*32 + d; }
   public int month()
   { return (value / 32) % 16; }
   public int day()
   { return value % 32; }
   public int year()
   { return value / 512; }
   public String toString()
   {  return month() + "/" + day()
}
```

Where do the numbers 512 and 32 come from, and why do we modulo by 16 when calculating the month.

Comment: `32` is the lowest `2**d` such that `2**d >= maximum possible day` we have `31` day at most (e.g. in December) so `2**d == 32` (`d == 5`); same principle for the months: we have `12` months and `2**m == 16` (`m == 4`). `16 * 32 == 512` (both months and days). In the algorithm provided we encode day as lowest `d == 5` bits and month with the next `m == 4` bits

Comment: It might have been slightly more obvious if it had said `value = (y*16 + m)*32 + d;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if your integer has 32 bits, then you can store in it all valid dates from 01-01-0001 up to (more or less) 01-01-8388608, where 8388608 is a year.
Also, the order of the integer values is the same as the natural order of dates.

But how is it done?

First observation is that all possible numbers of days in month fit into the interval [0, 31] (note that 0 will never be used).
Thus, you can store that using just five bits.

Similarly, all possible months fit into the interval [0, 15], so now you only need 4 bits.

Whole date is saved like this:

```
...011111100001  <---------- year
   ||||||||||||1100  <------ month
   ||||||||||||||||10011  <- day
------------------------
   011111100001110010011
```

If you want to get the value of the year, you have to get rid of the initial 9 bits. You can delete one bit by simply dividing the value by 2. To get rid of the 9 bits, you have to divide 9 times by 2, or - in one step - by 2^9 = 512.

In the above example, when you divide 011111100001110010011 by 2^9:

```
011111100001110010011
           1000000000 = 2^9
---------------------
011111100001
```

you get 011111100001 (or 2017 in decimal).

In short:

- division by 2^n == deleting last n bits of a number, shifting everything to the right.
- dividion modulo 2^n == looking only at the last n bits.

Comment: But are ints stored in two's complement, and would that have any effect on this.